# How can i show only the the files (path included) that contain a word using rgrep?

Tags: bash

I'm using this command below to find all the files that contain a string, but it shows not only the file but the line where the string is..

```
rgrep "foobar" .
```

How can show only the name of the files (path included)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the -l option

from grep man page:

```
-l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the
          first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: *The scanning will stop on the first match.* To be clear, `grep` will stop scanning the current file, and move on to the next if it has been given multiple args (or for some extended `grep`s the `-R` flag).